# Customization of math.js

Tags: math.js

Hello I have added the whole library to my project with this line "">" the problem is that is a heavy library and the page takes long time to initiate. I just need two features which are math.std (standard deviation) and math.median (average) so docent make scene to upload the whole thing. 
I dont know how to make the customization to use those features, I will be very to receive some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this page in the docs helps?

http://mathjs.org/docs/custom_bundling.html

Comment: Thak you a lot!